# Polymorphic BindingSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, polymorphism

I have a class hierarchy composed by 3 classes:

```
Customer
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Phone {get; set;}
   public string Address {get; set;}
   public abstract string Description {get;}
}

Person: Customer
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
   public overrides string Description { get { return this.Name + " " + this.Surname; } }
}

Company: Customer
{
   public string CompanyName {get; set;}
   public overrides string Description { get { return CompanyName; } }

}
```

I have a form with a BindingSource which obtains data from an Object Data Source based on Customer and I want to use the same form to enter and edit data for both companies and people.

I have several questions here:

1. Is it possible to bind some fields in the form to properties of the
   derived classes? How should I do it?
2. Is it worth to implement a
   façade/composition class exposing properties from the subclasses
   just to ease the binding?
3. Is it better, instead of relying on the
   binding features, to move data from/to the UI by code?

Comment: Shouldn't Person be your base class?  Is company really a Customer and a Person?

Comment: @SteveWellens No, I want the class hierarchy just as I defined it. Person and Company are Customers. The real problem is not about customers, companies and people, I simplified the case for clearity. It's not important for the sake of the question what class derives from what other class, the point here is how to implement data binding on a polymorphic data source and use the properties of the derived classes to bind controls.

Comment: You can take a look at some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067897/polymorphism-in-binding/22068055