# Polymorphism in binding?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, polymorphism

I have a POCO objects (public class with lots of public fields).

```
public class Poco
{
    public string name1;
    public string name2;
    public bool isName1Used;
}
```

Now i need to render a list of objects names, but with one condition: depending on bool, should be used name1 or name2. So, i made inherited class and add some functionality there

```
public class Item : Poco
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return isName1Used ? name1 : name2; }
    }
```

How can i now say to binding engine that it should bind to the Name?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

It says, Name is not found in Poco (fair enough, because engine doesn't know that it can polymorph Poco to Item).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to bind `Item` and not `Poco` elements to the view. Polymorphism isn't implicit just because you created an inherited class, you need to actually construct instances of that class and bind *them*.

```
var pocos = new List<Poco>();
var items = pocos.Select(i=>new Item
                         {
                            name1 = i.name1,
                            name2 = i.name2,
                            isName1Used = i.isName1Used
                         });
```

Comment: Hm.. maybe i should create a constructor for Item? Kinda Item(Poco poco) {name1 = poco.name1; *** }. But its looking like a cheating :) I'd prefer a way just to tell to binding engine that Poco is base for Item.

Comment: You can to simplify things. I merely stated the concept.

Comment: Hmmm.. maybe Converter can help? It would take Poco and return Item. Will it be much slower?

Comment: Slower in sense? You do have a quad core GHz processor to perform a few ifs, I am sure it can handle it.

Comment: I have an old good Lumia 800, which should handle it. I mean, does that makes any sense to use Converter from your point of view?

Comment: Yeah, I use converters for formatting and other stuff. It is convenient for "creating new properties"
 on the fly.